# Dropwizard doesn't log custom loggers to file

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard app, where I configured logger appenders to file as follows:

```
logging:
  level: INFO

  loggers:
    "mylogger": INFO
    "com.path.to.class": INFO

  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: .logs/mylogs.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: .logs/archive.%d.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 14
```

And, created logger in my app:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    

private final Logger OpLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("mylogger");
(and)
private final Logger ClassLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(pathToClass.class);
```

Do some test logging in main():

```
OpLogger.info("test 1");
ClassLogger.info("test 2);
```

The application starts and runs without problems; but I don't get any logs (except for Jetty access logs, of course, that are correctly printed to mylogs.log), neither in stdout or in mylogs.log file. Instead, if I remove the loggers configuration in configuration.yml, I get all logs printed to stdout.
Perhaps it's a problem of dropwizard or I have to add something to configuration.yml?
I'm using Dropwizard 0.8.0

Comment: You have default logging level INFO already, assigning INFO to certain classes is redundant at this point. Just FYI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE** The latest version of dropwizard supports logging configurations out of the box

I ran into the same issue trying to set up Dropwizard (0.8.4) with a separate files. I ran into the same issue. So I dug a bit deeper and found a solution for me (not the cleanest but I couldn't seem to get that working differently).

The issue is that `LoggingFactory#configure` automatically adds every appender to root. This is not very ideal so it needed overwriting. What I did was:

1. Overwrite `LoggingFactory`.

This is slightly messy since there is a few things that need to be copied sadly :( Here is my implementation:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException;
import javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.codahale.metrics.logback.InstrumentedAppender;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.jmx.JMXConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender;
import ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter;
import io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory;
import io.dropwizard.logging.LoggingFactory;

public class BetterDropWizardLoggingConfig extends LoggingFactory {

    @JsonIgnore
    final LoggerContext loggerContext;

    @JsonIgnore
    final PrintStream configurationErrorsStream;

    @JsonProperty("loggerMapping")
    private ImmutableMap<String, String> loggerMappings;

    private static void hijackJDKLogging() {
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    }

    public BetterDropWizardLoggingConfig() {
        PatternLayout.defaultConverterMap.put("h", HostNameConverter.class.getName());
        this.loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        this.configurationErrorsStream = System.err;
    }

    private Logger configureLevels() {
        final Logger root = loggerContext.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        loggerContext.reset();

        final LevelChangePropagator propagator = new LevelChangePropagator();
        propagator.setContext(loggerContext);
        propagator.setResetJUL(true);

        loggerContext.addListener(propagator);

        root.setLevel(getLevel());

        for (Map.Entry<String, Level> entry : getLoggers().entrySet()) {
            loggerContext.getLogger(entry.getKey()).setLevel(entry.getValue());
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(MetricRegistry metricRegistry, String name) {
        hijackJDKLogging();

        final Logger root = configureLevels();

        for (AppenderFactory output : getAppenders()) {
            Appender<ILoggingEvent> build = output.build(loggerContext, name, null);
            if(output instanceof MappedLogger && ((MappedLogger) output).getLoggerName() != null) {
                String appenderName = ((MappedLogger) output).getLoggerName();
                String loggerName = loggerMappings.get(appenderName);
                Logger logger = this.loggerContext.getLogger(loggerName);
                logger.addAppender(build);
            } else {
                root.addAppender(build);
            }
        }

        StatusPrinter.setPrintStream(configurationErrorsStream);
        try {
            StatusPrinter.printIfErrorsOccured(loggerContext);
        } finally {
            StatusPrinter.setPrintStream(System.out);
        }

        final MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        try {
            final ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("io.dropwizard:type=Logging");
            if (!server.isRegistered(objectName)) {
                server.registerMBean(new JMXConfigurator(loggerContext, server, objectName), objectName);
            }
        } catch (MalformedObjectNameException | InstanceAlreadyExistsException | NotCompliantMBeanException
                | MBeanRegistrationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        configureInstrumentation(root, metricRegistry);
    }

    private void configureInstrumentation(Logger root, MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        final InstrumentedAppender appender = new InstrumentedAppender(metricRegistry);
        appender.setContext(loggerContext);
        appender.start();
        root.addAppender(appender);
    }

}
```

As you can se, I sadly had to copy/paste a few private members and methods to make things work as intended.

I added a new field:

```
@JsonProperty("loggerMapping")
private ImmutableMap<String, String> loggerMappings;
```

This allows me to configure a mapping for each logger. This wasn't out of the box allowed as I can't get a name (dropwizard defaults the appender names, very inconvenient ...)

So I added a new Logger which in my case also does hostname substitution which I needed for different reasons. For this I overwrite the good old `FileAppenderFactory` and implement my own interface `MappedLogger`. Implementation here:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender;
import io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory;
import io.dropwizard.logging.FileAppenderFactory;

@JsonTypeName("hostnameFile")
public class HostnameFileAppender extends FileAppenderFactory implements AppenderFactory, MappedLogger {

    private static String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    public void setCurrentLogFilename(String currentLogFilename) {
        super.setCurrentLogFilename(substitute(currentLogFilename));
    }

    private String substitute(final String pattern) {
        String substitute = null;

        try {
            substitute = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to get local hostname:");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            substitute = uuid;
            System.err.println("Using " + substitute + " as fallback.");
        }
        return pattern.replace("${HOSTNAME}", substitute);
    }

    @Override
    public void setArchivedLogFilenamePattern(String archivedLogFilenamePattern) {
        super.setArchivedLogFilenamePattern(substitute(archivedLogFilenamePattern));
    }

    @Override
    public String getLoggerName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Please note that in order to add a new json type, you will have to follow the JavaDoc in `AppenderFactory` (Add Meta-inf to the classpath and make the new appender discoverable)

So far so good, we now have a config that can pick up on logger mappings, we have a logger that can take an optional name.

In the configure method I now tie those two together:

```
for (AppenderFactory output : getAppenders()) {
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> build = output.build(loggerContext, name, null);
        if(output instanceof MappedLogger && ((MappedLogger) output).getLoggerName() != null) {
            String appenderName = ((MappedLogger) output).getLoggerName();
            String loggerName = loggerMappings.get(appenderName);
            Logger logger = this.loggerContext.getLogger(loggerName);
            logger.addAppender(build);
        } else {
            root.addAppender(build);
        }
    }
```

For backwards compatibility I kept the default behaviour. If there is no name defined, the appender will be added to the root logger. Otherwise I resolve the typed logger and add the appender to it as wished.

And last but not least the good old yaml config:

```
logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

  loggers:
    "EVENT" : INFO

  loggerMapping:
    # for easier search this is defined as: appenderName -> loggerName rather than the other way around
    "eventLog" : "EVENT"

  appenders:
   - type: console   
     threshold: ALL
     logFormat: "myformat"

   - type: hostnameFile # NOTE THE NEW TYPE WITH HOSTNAME RESOLVE
     currentLogFilename: /Users/artur/tmp/log/my-${HOSTNAME}.log
     threshold: ALL
     archive: true
     archivedLogFilenamePattern: mypattern
     archivedFileCount: 31
     timeZone: UTC
     logFormat: "myFormat"

   - type: hostnameFile
     name: eventLog # NOTE THE APPENDER NAME
     currentLogFilename: something
     threshold: ALL
     archive: true
     archivedLogFilenamePattern: something
     archivedFileCount: 31
     timeZone: UTC
     logFormat: "myFormat"

   - type: hostnameFile
     currentLogFilename: something
     threshold: ERROR
     archive: true
     archivedLogFilenamePattern: something
     archivedFileCount: 31
     timeZone: UTC
     logFormat: "myFormat"
```

As you can see I am mapping the events appender to the events logger. This way all my events end up in file A, while the other information ends up somewhere else.

I hope this helps. Might not be the cleanest solution but I don't think Dropwizard allows this feature currently.

Comment: Hey - would it be possible for you to also include the `import`s to your example? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement separate logger with the dropwizard using logback.

1.Configure logger in your Application class (i.e application start point with main method) like below.

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
context.reset();
ContextInitializer initializer = new ContextInitializer(context);
initializer.autoConfig();
```

2.Configure logback.xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="OpLogger " class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/applicationname-mylogger.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="classLogger" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/applicationame-com.path.to.class.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="mylogger">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="OpLogger" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.path.to.class">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="classLogger" />
</logger>
</configuration>
```

3.Now use logger

```
static final Logger OpLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("mylogger");
static final Logger classLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.path.to.class");
```

**EDIT :**

I have try to implement the same logger in my example project. It works fine in my case. We can not use the LOGGER before the Dropwizard application initialize. The Dropwizard initialized only when you call

```
  new ExampleApplication().run(args);
```

So, if logger is used before Dropwizard initialized, your log will not be there. I have tried to implemented scenario with main method. The first log statement is not printed as we have used logger before the Dropwizard initialization, but the second log statement will be printed.

```
  OpLogger.info("test 1");
  new ExampleApplication().run(args);
  ClassLogger.info("test 2);
```

Hope this will help you out to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; but I already have Dropwizard that has Logback embedded; shouldn't I configure only the configuration.yml file?

Comment: Yes, Dropwizard uses logback internally. Can you please post your main method code where you try to use logger and call to new ExampleApplication().run(args); ? Also see my edited answer.