# DropWizard 0.7.1 logging file appender issues

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback, dropwizard

using DW 0.7.1 I successfully see my http request logs with the following configuration:

```
server:
  requestLog:
      appenders:
        - type: file
          currentLogFilename: /var/test/http-test.log
          archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/test/http-test-%d.log
          archivedFileCount: 5
          timeZone: UTC
```

however, with the logging yml entry for non http request logging configured as follows (using only the bare-bones definitions)

```
logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. 
  # Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: ERROR
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /var/test/test.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/test/test-%d.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
```

I *NEVER* see the logs at /var/test/

Instead, i see it the app just spool out default logging INFO level stuff, to console. Note: if i replace 'file' with console, the boot-strap start up tells me 'currentLogFilename isn't attribute of console' etc, so the DI is firing. It seems like if i use file though... I can't get it to go anywhere OTHER than console at default INFO levels.

Comment: looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483442/dropwizard-doesnt-log-custom-loggers-to-file?rq=1 is the same thing i'm experiencing

Comment: Change the logging level to Info from Error

Comment: logging level has no impact. ERROR is also perfectly valid

Comment: If you have logging level as ERROR, you will see logs only when there is an error. If there is no error, you wont see anything in logs

Comment: but as i said, its set to ERROR and file, and i see INFO to console.

Comment: ERROR/file should NOT write INFO to console.  

no file is ever created.  no matter what config i say, its always written to console at INFO level (which - are both defaults)

Comment: i set up a brand new DW project with EXACT same yml log config, and that works.  

i don't understand at all whats breaking in project 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was.

my ApiConfiguration (extension of io.dropwizard.Configuration) had attempted to bind to 'logging' value, explicitly, as follows

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty("logging")
private LoggingFactory loggingFactory = new LoggingFactory();
public LoggingFactory getLoggingFactory()
{
    return loggingFactory;
}
```

on a hunch, i simply removed the binding in ApiConfiguration and now the logs write to my expected /var/test/ location at the expected log level.